# RoomDB insert stuck when onConflict strategy is set

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users_table")
data class User(
  @PrimaryKey val id: String,
  val name: String = "",
  val surname: String = "",
  val email: String = "",
  val phone: String = "",
  val likes: List<String> = listOf()
)
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
abstract class UsersDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE id=:uid")
  abstract fun observeUser(uid: String): Observable<User>

  @Query("SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE id=:uid")
  abstract fun selectUser(uid: String): Single<User>

  @Insert
  abstract fun insertUser(user: User): Completable

  @Update
  abstract fun updateUser(user: User): Completable
}
```

When I call `insertUser` first time, it passes no problem. When I call it second time, it throws an error because there is a conflict in the DB, cause of the `@PrimaryKey`. When I add `onConflict=OnCoinflictStrategy.REPLACE` to the `@Insert` annotation, it never completes. I have put breakpoint into the generated classes and both `beginTransaction` and `endTransaction` is called inside.
These are called inside my source:

```
    override fun fetchUser(): Completable =
      authProvider.signedInUserUid
        .flatMap { apiService.getUser(it) }
        .flatMapCompletable { usersDao.insertUser(it) }
        .doOnError { Timber.e(it) }
        .onErrorComplete()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

**UPDATE:** When `flatMapCompletable` completes, it does not continue. Why? When I simulate and return `Completable.error()` and chain `onErrorComplete` it continues as expected. When `onErrorComplete` removed it ends with error as expected. Why it is not continuing when it completes? `fetchUser` is called in another rx method which is subscribed in the view model:

```
    override fun isSignedIn(): Completable =
      currentUserExists()
        .andThen(Completable.defer { fetchUser() })
        .onErrorResumeNext {
            Timber.d("Failed initial $it")
            when (it) {
                is SignInException -> signInAnonymously()
                is NoInternetConnection -> Completable.error(it)
                else -> throw NotImplementedError("${it::class.java.name} no implemented")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was not completing is that `authProvider.signedInUserUid` is a `BehaviorSubject`. The `flatMapCompletable` doesn't complete until the starting stream, in this case `signedInUserUid` completes.
Replaced the `BehaviorSubject` with a method returning `Observable.just()` fixed the issue as it completes after emitting the value.